# How to group data from attributes using for loops in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to work out how to group data at two levels using for loops in VueJS

As an example I have a VueJS app with the following data:

```
cars: [{
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang"
}, {
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "Thunderbird"
}, {
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "Fairlane"
}, {
  "make": "Chevrolet",
  "model": "Camaro"
}, {
  "make": "Chevrolet",
  "model": "Chevelle"
}, {
  "make": "Plymouth",
  "model": "Barracuda"
}]
```

It's straightforward to loop through the cars using a for loop:

```
<div v-for="car in cars">
  <div>Make: {{ car.make }}</div>
  <div>Model: {{ car.model }}</div>  
</div>
```

But what if I wanted to group the models by make? The output I'm after is:

```
Ford
  Mustang
  Thunderbird
  Fairlane
Chevrolet
  Camaro
  Chevelle
Plymouth
  Barracuda
```

What's the best way to do this in VueJS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@DigitalDrifter has a fine solution, but you might find the following easier to read. It is less efficient, though, so I definitely wouldn't use it for large collections (e.g. thousands of cars).

```
computed: {
    makes() {
        const makes = new Set();
        this.cars.forEach(car => makes.add(car.make);
        return Array.from(makes); 
    }
},
methods: {
    models(make) {
        return this.cars
            .filter(car => car.make === make)
            .map(car => car.model);
    }
}
```

and in the template

```
<div v-for="(make, index) in makes" :key="index">
    <p>Make: {{ make }}</p>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(model, innerIndex) in models(make)" :key="innerIndex">
            {{ model }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found this easier to understand.

Comment: The anwer have syntax error, computed routine missing a ')'.

Comment: i need this as well in vue 3. gonna try it later.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reduce` in a computed property:

```
computed: {
  groups () {
    return this.cars.reduce((carry, current) => {
      if (carry.hasOwnProperty(current.make) && Array.isArray(carry[current.make])) {
        carry[current.make].push(current.model)
      } else {
        Object.assign(carry, { [current.make]: [current.model] })
      }
      return carry
    }, {})
  }
}
```

The template can loop the groups like:

```
<div v-for="(make, index) in Object.keys(groups)" :key="index">
  <p>Make: {{ make }}</p>
  <ul>
  <li v-for="(model, innerIndex) in groups[make]" :key="innerIndex">
    {{ model }}
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why waste so much cpu on computed rather than doing some data massage that have a structure which is ui friendly?

```
props: { 
  cars: Array 
},
data() {
  return {
    makes: _.groupBy(this.cars, 'make'); // _.groupBy is a lodash function
  };
},
methods: {
  // some CRUD methods
  add() {},
  update() {},
  delete() {},
  reconstruct() {
    var result = [];
    Object.keys(this.makes).forEach(key => {
      result.push(...this.makes[key]);
    });
    return result;
  }
}

<div v-for="(make, key) in makes" :key="key">
<p>Make: {{ make }}</p>
<ul>
    <li v-for="(car, index) in make" :key="index">
        {{ car.model }}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

You only needs to construct/deconstruct when talking to APIs.

Comment: You can import single lodash function. Using computed is also 'at least' two loops, one on receive data from API response, one on any CRUD method performed.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of `computed` property as follow, (run this code snippet to see) :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      cars : [{
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang"
}, {
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "Thunderbird"
}, {
  "make": "Ford",
  "model": "Fairlane"
}, {
  "make": "Chevrolet",
  "model": "Camaro"
}, {
  "make": "Chevrolet",
  "model": "Chevelle"
}, {
  "make": "Plymouth",
  "model": "Barracuda"
}]
  },
  computed: {
      groupedMakes() {
          var makes={};
          this.cars.forEach((item)=>{
         if(makes[item.make]==undefined){
              makes[item.make]=[];
              makes[item.make].push(item.model)
                }
          else{
            makes[item.make].push(item.model);

            }
           });
         
           return makes;
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(make,index) in groupedMakes">
        <h3>{{index}}</h3>
         <ul>
            <li v-for="model in make">
            {{model}}
            </li>
         </ul> 
    </div>
   
</div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```